# Find a stable way to compute the function

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Say I have this function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\text{e}^x-x}{\sin(x)}$$

And I want to reduce the error when $x\approx0$ and find
a stable way to compute the function. More accurate wording, how can the function be written in such a way that the error is reduced?

Comment: What error are you asking about?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right expression?  I don't see any obvious cancellation as x gets near 0.  The numerator goes to (1-0) and the denominator goes to 0 so....

Comment: loss of significance

Comment: What would be wrong with a simple Taylor expansion $f(x)=\frac 1x+\frac 23x+o(x)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean error when computed with floating point numbers (e.g. float or double)?

Comment: @zwim It is a Laurent expansion because of the $1/x$-term, but this is a good idea.

Comment: @Peter Unless I'm mistaken I think we talk about Taylor series and Laurent series for infinite summation of $x^n$ terms, but about Taylor expansions when we stop at an order $o(\cdots)$ and the terms are not necessarily $x^n$ (can have log for instance). In French I use DL (limited developpement) instead so there is no ambiguity...

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{\sin(x)}$ ?

Comment: Claude Leibovici
 The truth is that I also thought about it, but in the exercise it is written exactly as I mentioned.

Comment: Somnium

Yes that what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Near $0$ you need to expand all terms (into the Taylor series) and cancel $x$:
$$
\frac{\text{e}^x-1}{\sin(x)}=\frac{x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots}{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots}=\frac{1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+\dots}{1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\dots}
$$
This formula can be numerically evaluated without problems. If you need a code evaluating this function for any value, then you need this expansion for $x\in[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$, where $\varepsilon$ can be explicitly determined  (for the required accuracy), and the original formula for $x$ outside of this interval.

Answer (score 2):

*Similar to @Vítězslav Štembera's answer*

Better than Taylor series are Padé approximants : for example
$$\frac{e^x-1}{\sin(x)}=\frac {1+\frac{3 }{14}x+\frac{11 }{84}x^2 } {1-\frac{2 }{7}x-\frac{5 }{84}x^2 }$$ gives an asymptotic error of $\frac{53 }{10080}x^5$

$$\frac{e^x-x}{\sin(x)}=\frac 1 x\, \frac{1-\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{41 }{80}x^2 } {1-\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{37 }{240}x^2 }$$